# how to use value of local variable in another method?

Tags: iphone, xcode

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


}

-(id)initwithinfo2:(NSInteger)pass_wordID2
{
    NSLog(@"pass_wordID:%d",pass_wordID2);


}
```

I want to use pass_wordID2 in viewDidLoad. How ?

Answer (score 2):

Make an Instance Varibale in the *.h file. Than do it like this in initWithInfo2:

```
yourInstanceVariable = pass_wordID2;
```

Than you can use `yourInstanceVariable` in `viewDidLoad`. ;-)

Comment: myInstanceVariable get reset to 0. I am not able to get value of it.

Comment: if you use your initwithinfo2 method to initialize your instance, than you have to change the following to your method:
if(self = [super init]) {
    yourInstanceVariable = pass_wordID2;
}
than it should work...